# How to calculate the largest possible file you can create given a block size and number of direct pointers?

Tags: filesystems

I am trying to find the largest possible file that I can create on a UNIX (FFS) system with 12 direct pointers, and a 2kb block size. I have looked around a lot trying to find some sort of formula, or direction, the closest I've found is from a [university quiz answer sheet](https://pages.cs.wisc.edu/%7Edusseau/Classes/CS537-F04/Questions/sol16.html).

Based on the solution to their question I tried to calculate the largest file for my scenario which was (I am assuming the other parts of their formula is because of the indirect pointers):

```
(12 * 2KB) = 24KB
```

However, I have no way to verify my solution. How do I properly calculate the largest possible file size?

Comment: I'm not sure it's that useful to reason about "a UNIX filesystem". The ones in practical use vary in how they do their bookkeeping, and e.g. on Linux, ext4 can use either that pointer table hell, or lists of extents stored in a tree, which works in a completely different manner. Then there's XFS, ZFS, and all the *BSD filesystems, with what ever it is they do. I mean, unless you mean some ancient system that was actually called UNIX(tm), but then you're researching history.

Comment: @ilkkachu FFS is what I'm trying to refer to. I updated the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With 12 direct pointers, each to a 2 kB block, the largest file you can have is 24 kB as you have correctly calculated. There is no easy way to verify it, you need a file system debugger to show you the on disk data structures.

Once you have indirect pointers you need to know how many pointers you can fit into 2 kB. If one assumes they are 4 bytes each, then you can fit 512 of them, and so each indirect block gives you an additional 1 MB (512 * 2 kB).

Once you have double indirection then you need to know how many can fit in the space described by an indirect block. For 1 MB and 4 byte pointers this is 256 kB, so a double indirect block allows for 512 MB.

Some filesystems use a (start, length) pair to describe a continuous run of blocks on the disk. If you have 6 such pairs rather than 12 pointers then depending on how fragmented the disk is you can specify between 12 KB and 6 * 2<sup>32</sup> * 2 KB or about 36 TB.

Comment: Thank you for such a clear and precise answer. Especially on the indirect pointers part.

Comment: those would probably be bytes, with an uppercase B; not bits, with a lowercase b.